# Am I able to use environmental variables in connection strings while using Visual Studio and MS Access?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

I am trying to create an application that uses MS Access as the back end. However, I wish to share the application across desktops to different users (thus `C:\Users\....` will differ).

We have a file that is shared across all desktops which contains the MS Access database. However, the database and app are stored in directories which differ with the users name.

An example is

```
C:\Users\MyName\Application\Database\Database.accdb
```

But on someone else's desktop it will be:

```
C:\Users\TheirName\Application\Database\Database.accdb
```

As you can see the directories are almost identical except for the users name.

My connection string currently reads

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Users\MyName\App\Name\Access Database\Database.accdb"
```

I was wondering, that since the app won't work on others computers due to this directory mishap, if there was a way to incorporate %HOMEPATH% within the connection string/datasource ,thus, it will automatically redirect to the users custom name and the app will be able to find the database.

Below is my current App.config file. I have been trying implement %HOMEPATH% within it but cant seem to do so.

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ItemForm.Properties.Settings.Access_DatabaseConnectionString"
             connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=&quot;C:\Users\MyName\App\Name\Access Database\Database.accdb&quot;"
             providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can put `Application\Database\Database.accdb` in App.config and create the entire connection string at runtime with above value for App.config and %HOMEPATH% environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but how would I go about that with the current code I have above?

Comment: *I have a file that is shared across all desktops which contains the MS Access database*. Not a good idea. Put your database on a network connection.